# What is the evolutionary reason behind human preference for salty foods?

Tags: evolution, food, diet

It's been established that [food palatability is related to it's caloric density](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9216570). This hypothesis is used to explain why humans are partial to sugar and fat. But it is also said that humans are partial to salt.

Given that salt has no calories, are there evolutionary reasons that explain why humans have a preference for salty foods?

Answer (score 4):

The body needs more than energy to survive.

Salt is vital to the body's function. Ions of sodium and calcium perform numerous vital functions, but are particularly related to the function of the nervous system and contraction of muscles. Accordingly, seeking out sources of salt makes sense in a natural environment in which salt is relatively unavailable.